# parent.window.opener stops execution

Tags: javascript, firefox, window, parent-child

I have a code in vb , where I have the following lines

```
alert("1");
parent.window.opener=true;
alert("2");
parent.window.close();
```

This code executes fine in all browsers except Firefox. In Firefox am able to get `alert("1");`, but when the `parent.window.opener` is executed it interupts there. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.opener` is supposed to be a Window.  If you set it to something that's not a Window object, per spec it's supposed to throw an exception.

Which is what Firefox does (but apparently not the other browsers you tested?).  There should have been a corresponding exception reported in your console; was there not?